# [test.launch] is neither a launch file in package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in src there is a package named relaxed_astar including: CMakeLists.text package.xml and launch
inside the launch folder there's file name test.launch

when i run this command `roslaunch relaxed_astar test.launch`

i get in error say

```
[test.launch] is neither a launch file in package [relaxed_astar] nor is [relaxed_astar] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

and the test.launch file code is

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch"></include>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch">
    <arg name="rgb_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
  </include>

  <arg name="map_file" default="map_folder/your_map_file.yaml"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216217/%5Btest.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possibly, it is related with your workspace and package path. Please make sure that you sourced the bash file, i.e; **source /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash**

If so, your package setup may be the problem. Your package should be listed when you run **rospack find relaxed_astar** .

If these are not related, please supply more details like directory tree of your workspace and contents of package.xml file.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-20**:
****-Does the file actually exists? Yes, the file is in the launch folder.

-Did you source the setup.bash file? Do you mean source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash ? Yes, I did.

-What does rospack find relaxed_astar output? [rospack] Error: stack/package relaxed_astar not found

what's Next Please

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-08-20**:
With setup.bash file I do not mean /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash. I mean the setup.bash file of your workspace. It is located in your workspace, in "devel" folder, as I mentioned in my answer above (source /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash).

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-08-20**:
Go to foulder where you have your work_space (normally your catkin_ws), open the file .bashrc is hiden,
and seach if you have:
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /home/(username)/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash .
Can do rospack find relaxed_astar or rospack profile(list all packages)

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-20**:
**Would you please answer my question[CLICK HERE PLEASE](http://answers.ros.org/question/216229/rviz-robot-model-error/) in this link**

**Comment by [Raul Gui](https://answers.ros.org/users/14636/raul-gui/) on 2015-08-20**:
you solve your problem?

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-20**:
Yes, Thank you for your help

**Comment by [Annunaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/28702/annunaki/) on 2016-12-03**:
i have kinda the same problem ,,the roslaunch cannot find stdr_launchers ,, and i did the source commands ,, but i cannot find the .bashrc in the catkin_ws directory ,, is that normal or im missing that file ? ,thanks